# Using RegEx to match characters between two symbols and copy it to a location

Tags: arrays, powershell, foreach

I have directory of files and my goal is matching a 5 digit zip code and copying it to another set of specific folders.

I know there are a number of ways to do this but sometimes the zip code shows up twice in the file name so I have to match the zip code in between ^ and % such that the entire filename is like: *mjn22182aguygbc^12350%abc.pdf*.

Another assumption is the destination location has preset folders named the zip code such as: *d:\queries\12350*.

My goal is to move *mjn22182aguygbc^12350%abc.pdd* to *d:\queries\12350* if the zip code exists in some list i can read in and if it is not part of the zip codes, the file stays in the source folder.

So far I have the following but the all files are being copied into my root destination folder and not the folders that I've created eg 12350 and I'm having trouble :

```
$dstpath = "D:\queries"   
$filterlist = @("12350","90182")
$fileList = Get-ChildItem -Path $srcpath -Force -Recurse

foreach ($currentfile in $fileList)
{
    foreach($zip in $filterLists)
    {
    $currentzip = $currentfile.Name -match '(?<=\^)[0-9]+(?=%)';
    if($currentzip -in $filterlist)
        {
        Move-Item -Path $($file.FullName) -Destination $dstpath
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The regex is right, but all -match does is return true.

```
'mjn22182aguygbc^12350%abc.pdd' -match '(?<=\^)[0-9]+(?=%)'
True
```

The match would be contained in $matches.0 afterwards.

```
$matches.0
12350
```

You're moving to $dstpath.  There's no reason it would go anywhere else.